# Is it possible to use Android API to create a google account using a custom Form?

Tags: android, account, accountmanager

I'm working on a Welcome app for a new firmware. 
This app will run right after a factory reset.
I would like to know if there's a way to create a google account (if the new user doesn't have one already) for contacts and callendar sync.
I've got the SimpleSyncAdapter sample and I'm having a hard time figure out how to use that with a custom activity form that will be one step of the tutorial/welcome app. In the google sample the AuthenticatorActivity starts an AuthenticationService that instantiates the Authentication class.

The Authentication class has the following method:

```
public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType,
    String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) {

    final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AuthenticatorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AuthenticatorActivity.PARAM_AUTHTOKEN_TYPE, authTokenType);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
    return bundle;
}
```

But I'm not able to instantiate the Authentication class that extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator in my AccountActivity. Also, I'm not sure if this will rly help me. It's not clear to me what this method does.

Can anyone shed some light?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this webpage: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=0fc7c28920b60576&hl=en

Comment: True, you cant create normal @gmail.com email's, Probably also to prevent spam.

Comment: so... I need to have a Google Aps professional or educational account for that project in order to create that custom google account creation and authentication screen?

Comment: there is a free version for google apps, however, its limited to 50 users (if im correct), just have a look over here: http://www.google.com/a/cpanel/premier/new?hl=en